# Fortran extension in Python wheel

Tags: python, numpy, fortran, pypi, python-wheel

I want to build a python package to upload to [PyPI](https://pypi.org/) with compiled fortran code, so the user doesn't have to have any fortran compiler.
To do this, I've made an extension to my package in the `setup.py` file:

```
import io
from os import path as op
from setuptools import find_packages
from numpy.distutils.core import Extension, setup

with open('README.md') as readme_file:
    readme = readme_file.read()

here = op.abspath(op.dirname(__file__))

# get the dependencies and installs
with io.open(op.join(here, "requirements.txt"), encoding="utf-8") as f:
    all_reqs = f.read().split("\n")

install_requires = [x.strip() for x in all_reqs if "git+" not in x]
dependency_links = [x.strip().replace("git+", "") for x in all_reqs if "git+" not in x]

requirements = [ ]

setup_requirements = [ ]

test_requirements = [ ]

erf_extension = Extension(name='intelligen.fortran.functions',
                          sources=['intelligen/fortran/erf.f', 'intelligen/fortran/erf.pyf'],
                          extra_link_args=["-static", "-static-libgfortran", "-static-libgcc"])

setup(
    author="Diego Bouchet",
    author_email='diegobouchet88@gmail.com',
    python_requires='>=3.5',
    install_requires=install_requires,
    dependency_links=dependency_links,
    license="MIT license",
    long_description=readme,
    long_description_content_type='text/markdown',
    include_package_data=True,
    keywords='intelligen',
    name='intelligen',
    packages=find_packages(include=['intelligen', 'intelligen.*']),
    setup_requires=setup_requirements,
    test_suite='tests',
    tests_require=test_requirements,
    url='https://github.com/Bouchet07/intelligen',
    version='0.12.2',
    zip_safe=False,
    ext_modules=[erf_extension],
)
```

The `requirements.txt` is:

```
numpy
matplotlib
```

This works for me, when I do `pip install -e .` the package works fine, with the fortran code, and when I run `python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel` and upload to PyPI with `twine upload dist/*`, I can succesfully run `pip install intelligen` (the name of my package) and it works, but I tried in a different computer and it doesn't work. I get this:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\usuario\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:\users\usuario\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpe6a8v106'
       cwd: C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-e_38naxi\intelligen_5ad9e25d759146c88a2da9bade5f8dcb
  Complete output (36 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running config_cc
  INFO: unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
  running config_fc
  INFO: unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
  running build_src
  INFO: build_src
  INFO: building extension "intelligen.fortran.functions" sources
  INFO: f2py options: []
  INFO:   adding 'build\src.win-amd64-3.9\build\src.win-amd64-3.9\intelligen\fortran\fortranobject.c' to sources.
  INFO:   adding 'build\src.win-amd64-3.9\build\src.win-amd64-3.9\intelligen\fortran' to include_dirs.
  INFO: build_src: building npy-pkg config files
  running build_py
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\intelligen
  copying intelligen\AI.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\intelligen
  copying intelligen\constants.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\intelligen
  copying intelligen\integrate.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\intelligen
  copying intelligen\intelligen.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\intelligen
  copying intelligen\interpolate.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\intelligen
  copying intelligen\linregress.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\intelligen
  copying intelligen\numeric.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\intelligen
  copying intelligen\signals.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\intelligen
  copying intelligen\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\intelligen
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\intelligen\stats
  copying intelligen\stats\distributions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\intelligen\stats
  copying intelligen\stats\functions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\intelligen\stats
  copying intelligen\stats\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\intelligen\stats
  running build_ext
  INFO: No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  INFO: customize MSVCCompiler
  INFO: customize MSVCCompiler using build_ext
  INFO: CCompilerOpt.cc_test_flags[1021] : testing flags (/O2)
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  INFO: CCompilerOpt.cache_flush[817] : write cache to path -> C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-e_38naxi\intelligen_5ad9e25d759146c88a2da9bade5f8dcb\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-39\Release\ccompiler_opt_cache_ext.py
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for intelligen
Failed to build intelligen
ERROR: Could not build wheels for intelligen which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Why this doesn't work for any computer like [scipy](https://github.com/scipy/scipy), which has fortran code too?

I have windows with a MinGW-64 installation with gfortran
If you want to explore something in my code, it's here: [intelligen](https://github.com/Bouchet07/intelligen)

Comment: SciPy provides binary wheels for all supported Python versions on all supported platforms: https://pypi.org/project/scipy/#files

Comment: And there is a way I can do the same? Maybe not too difficult

Comment: The way is to compile on all combinations of Python and platforms. Most probably using a CI like AppVeyor, Circle, Github Actions, Travis. Difficult, yes. No way around that.